# 400 Bad request from flask when using a page from a sub folder & submitting a form

Tags: python, html, http, flask, httprequest

Whenever I request the page, it loads fine, but when I submit the form, I receive a 400 bad request,I believe it may be to do with the actual `html` , but I cannot figure out what.

**Html file** `/admin/dashboard.html` :

```
<div class="container">
    <p><strong>Shut down server?</strong></p>
    <form action="/" method="POST">
        <input class="btn btn-danger" id="fred" name="fred" type="submit"         value="fred"></input> 
    </form>
</div>
```

**Python file** :

```
@app.route('/admin/dashboard', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def admin_dashboard():
 if request.method == 'GET':
      return render_template("/admin/dashboard.html")
 if request.method == 'POST':
      if request.form['submit'] == 'fred':
           admin.log("Shutting down...")
           #os._exit(1)
      else:
           return render_template("/admin/dashboard.html")
      return render_template("/admin/dashboard.html")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are posting to the `/` path, but the view that handles your post is at `/admin/dashboard`.  Remove the `action="/"` line from your form since it's the same url that rendered the page.

If you do need a different url, use `url_for('name_of_endpoint')`.  For example, to generate the url for `def admin_dashboard():`, you use `url_for('admin_dashboard')`.

Additionally, you named your input 'fred', so you need to access `request.form['fred']`, or change the name of the input to 'submit'.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if a field with name `submit` is present in the request:

```
if request.form['submit'] == 'fred':
```

But there is no such field, the field is actually named `fred`:

```
<input class="btn btn-danger" id="fred" name="fred" type="submit" value="fred"></input>
```

You should either change the request check:

```
if request.form['fred'] == 'fred':
```

Or change the inputs name:

```
<input class="btn btn-danger" id="fred" name="submit" type="submit" value="fred"></input>
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quickly, I tried both things you suggested and it still returned a 400 bad request

Answer (score -1):

In Flask doc

> We recommend accessing URL parameters with get or by catching the
>   KeyError because users might change the URL and presenting them a 400
>   bad request page in that case is not user friendly.

so  maybe you can try

```
request.form.get('submit', '')
```

so your code:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
  if request.form.get('submit') == 'fred':
       admin.log("Shutting down...")
       #os._exit(1)
  else:
       return render_template("/admin/dashboard.html")
  return render_template("/admin/dashboard.html")
```